# Operator '==' error

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, operators

all

I have some code:

```
if (bind(this->socketListen, (SOCKADDR*)& this->addr, sizeof(this->addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   cerr << "Failed to bind the address to our listening socket. Winsock 
            Error:" << to_string(WSAGetLastError()) << endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

First line of this code generates an errors:

`E0349 no operator "==" matches these oparands`

and

`C2678 binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforces,SOCKET &,SOCKADDR *,unsigned int>'(or there is no acceptable conversion)`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you wrote `using namespace std` in your code somewhere

Comment: Maybe you can try overloading operator `==`

Comment: @21koizyd I don't believe that's the right approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks much like the compiler is confusing your `bind()` call with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Most likely because you have written `using namespace std;` somewhere before, and the `<functional>` header is included.

The easiest fix is probably you tell explicitly you want `bind()` from the global namespace:

```
if (::bind(this->socketListen, (SOCKADDR*)& this->addr, sizeof(this->addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
 // ^^
```

It would be better though to get rid of `using namespace std;` and either use specific `using` statements for what you need from `namespace std` like

```
 using std::cin;
```

or simply prefix `std::` where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions

1. remove `using namespace std` - this is best but will probably throw up a lot of compilation errors

Or

2. Quick and dirty write `::bind`

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT WRITE `using namespace std;`!

When you write that, you must completely understand C++ standard around  ADL(Argument Dependent Look-up).

You can use `using namespace` only when you use UDLs(User Defined Literals)'s operator function(like `using namespace std::string_literals;`).